# LLVM Error : External function could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, llvm, llvm-ir

I am reading the LLVM's Kaleidoscope tutorial (http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html).

I wanted to compile and test the language. After some compiler's errors (EngineBuilder and Module's constructor, linking libs...), the example program was built. Then, I tried the language. I got a few problems with InitializeNativeTargets, DataLayoutPass... But I managed to correct them.

Howewer, I don't manage to resolve one error. When I write `extern printd(x); printd(5);`, the program doesn't work : "LLVM ERROR : Program used external function 'printd' which could not be resolved".

I looked for the solution on the net. I read a lot of webpages, but nothing worked.

How can I resolve this problem ? Why LLVM can't find the external function 'printd', which is included in the program ? Thanks in advance for your answer.

The used code : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qb-zUGaUUIF354uFCXv1iuq8n_rjya6IHDW4WCPWN_4/edit?usp=sharing

The .pro file (Qt Creator) :

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = Kaleidoscope
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += /home/alainetflo/Documents/me/C++/LLVM/llvm-3.5.0.src/include
DEPENDPATH += /home/alainetflo/Documents/me/C++/LLVM/llvm-3.5.0.src/include

LIBS += `llvm-config --ldflags --libs all --system-libs` -Wl,-no-as-needed

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -m32
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -rdynamic -std=c++11 -O3
```

I use GCC 4.8.2, LLVM 3.5 and Qt 5.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 32bits.

Comment: Where are you writing that? In that same cpp file? Why not just calling the function? I suppose extern isn't needed

Comment: I think you should clarify the problem by providing a more compact example that illustrates the problem. In the used code I can see only a single file with the implementation of the function `printd` but not where it is actually used. The only thing that I can suggest you to try is to check whether you also have declared the function as `extern "C"` in the file where you want to use it, your question suggests that you only declared is as plain `extern` (without `"C"`) and the name mangling hits you.

Comment: I wrote all the code in the same file : main.cpp. I'm sorry if I was not clear : I wrote the "extern printd(x)[...]" in the console during the program's execution (the program is an interpreter). So, extern is needed otherwise the program throws a syntax error.

Comment: perhaps I got it: you're parsing something from the console and trying to JIT from the IR the printd function, right? But how do you translate the function body into the IR? I don't see any code to do it

Comment: According to the tutorial, the console is indeed parsed. Thanks to LLVM's JIT, I can run the code. The "printd(5); instruction" in the interpreter should called the printd function in the C++ code. The instruction "extern printd(5);" should declared (and linked) the function. Is that clear ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found a great link on the net : http://koichitamura.blogspot.fr/2011/01/since-i-went-to-held-several-weeks-ago.html.

The error came from the wrong place of the `-rdynamic` argument in the .pro file (`-rdynamic` must be after the linking options). You need this argument because (GCC man page) :

> This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table.

I changed the .pro file :

```
QT       += core    
QT       -= gui    
TARGET = Test01
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle    
TEMPLATE = app   
SOURCES += main.cpp    
INCLUDEPATH += /home/alainetflo/Documents/me/C++/LLVM/llvm-3.5.0.src/include
DEPENDPATH += /home/alainetflo/Documents/me/C++/LLVM/llvm-3.5.0.src/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 \
/usr/include/c++/4.8

LIBS += `llvm-config --ldflags --libs all --system-libs` -Wl,-no-as-needed -rdynamic

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -m32

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g -std=c++11 -O3
```

In this way, the program works with no error ! (The tutorial's example runs (http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl6.html#kicking-the-tires))

Comment: guess this must result from the mechanism of jit; but i remember that 1 year ago i can compile w/o `-rdynamic` link flags

Comment: In any case, this argument is required with LLVM 3.5 and GCC 4.8. With what did you compile ? Or, is this the mechanism of jit ?

Comment: cannot remember clearly, it was still llvm2.9 and gcc4.4 then; sorry i don't know much about jit.