# Where is std::endl in my compiled standard library?

Tags: c++, llvm, libc++

I am trying to find functions from my C++ standard library by their mangled name. I am on macOS, so using the `nm` command I can inspect a `dylib`:

```
nm -g /usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib
nm -g /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.dylib
```

In the output, I can find the mangled names for `std::cout`:

```
0000000000079ec0 S __ZNSt3__14coutE
0000000000079f60 S __ZNSt3__15wcoutE
etc...
```

However, I do not find any entries for `std::endl`.

Interestingly, my LLVM IR interpreter also cannot find `std::endl`, although `std::cout` works fine:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function     
'__ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_' which could not be resolved!
```

Where should I expect to find `std::endl` on my system?

Comment: Can you try to find `std::flush`?

Comment: I suspect `std::endl` not to be linked as it's simply `<< '\n' << std::flush`

Comment: `std::flush` seems to be present: `0000000000011bb0 T __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv`

Comment: @YSC I agree, but which library should I link? I cannot find `std::endl` where I expect to!

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482535/llvm-error-external-function-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: It might be a header-only function.

Comment: And if you use a C++ compiler frontend, like `g++` or `clang++` to build your programs, or use an IDE like XCode, then you don't need to explicitly link with any library to get access to the standard library. So can you please tell us what the *actual* problem is? *Why* do you want to know where `std::endl` is located?

Comment: XY problem? Why did you look for it in the first place?

Comment: It's probably a template, so it needs to be available in source code, and cannot be compiled into a library (unless specifically instructed to contain an instantiation).

Comment: To summarise, problem 1: std::endl is not a function (it's a function template) and cannot be compiled to object code; problem 2: normally you shouldn't explicitly link standard libraries (whether for C or C++), the compiler frontend knows better where the standard libraries are.

Comment: @n.m.: Thought you were addressing the stuff he's seeing in his dump. My point remains, the things in his `nm` excerpt are variables, not functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt right, because functions are few and far between in this part of the library. It's all templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As YSC mentioned, `std::endl` is a function (that is probably inlined), and all it does is output the end line `\n` character then call `flush`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

Looks like libcxx has *hidden* endl: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ostream#L999

While flush does not have such an attribute: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ostream#L938

Comment: Uhm... it's [clearly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) a template, so that is the reason, why it doesn't get compiled into the C++ standard library. Whether it gets inlined or not is another matter altogether.

Comment: So? The OP never indicated, that `std::flush` would be exported from their C++ Standard Library either. I don't understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: My, bad. Misunderstood the question. Possibly could be due to visibility attributes, if any, applied to the functions?

Comment: This answer contains the solution: it is not part of the compiled library because it is a function in the header. It is also `inline`, which was causing trouble for `lli`.